# Getting Access Violation stemming from Windows.UI.Xaml.dll in C# WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, access-violation

I have a WinRT app in which I have a page with a `Button`. The button opens up one of our Settings Flyouts. In order to do this, button's `Click` event is asynchronous.

In the Flyout's class I have an asynchronous Show() method which returns a Task, much like MessageDialogs. The method initializes a `ResultCompletionSource<object>`, along with a `Popup`. It opens the `Popup`, then returns the `ResultCompletionSource<T>.Task` so that it can be awaited on.

In order that multiple Panes not be created, I have it set `Button.IsEnabled` to `false` immediately upon button press, and return it to `true` after the completion of the event (and awaiting the Task).

**The problem I am having is that if a user were to rapidly click the button in question, eventually it crashes the app, and unpredictably so. Sometimes it's after 4 clicks, sometimes after 20.**

I've tried catching the exception and finding out where it is in the debugger. Finding it required debugging with the Native debugger (well, I did Mixed). The exception is a win32 Access Violation exception that is stems from Windows.UI.Xaml.dll.

Is something not getting marshalled back to the UI thread possibly? The `Popup` which has the Flyout as its `Child` has `LightDismissEnabled = true`, which is what (in this scenario) calls the `Closed` event, which in turn sets the Result of the `TaskCompletionSource`.

Some basic code describing the issue:

In CustomFlyout:

```
public Task<object> ShowAsync()
{
    resultCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    parentPopup = new Popup();
    //Set all of the height/width/bounds of the popup, along with setting the Closed Event.

    parentPopup.Child = this;
    parentPopup.IsOpen = true;

    return resultCompletionSource.Task;
}

void parentPopup_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    if(resultCompletionSource != null)
    {
        resultCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
    }

    try
    {
        (sender as Popup).Closed -= parentPopup_closed;
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Button click in my page:

```
private async void ShowFlyout_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowFlyout_Button.IsEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        CustomSettingsFlyout flyout = new CustomSettingsFlyout();
        await flyout.ShowAsync()
    }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        ShowFlyout_Button.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

I don't have access to the C UIElement source, but the debugger/disassembler gave me this stack trace:

```
>Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CUIElement::GetRedirectionTransformsAndParentCompNode(CRenderTarget * pRenderTarget, TransformAndClipStack * pTransformsToParentCompNode, CMILMatrix * pTransformToRoot, unsigned int * pIsTransformToRootAnimating, unsigned int * pAreAllAncestorsVisible, HWCompTreeNode * * ppNearestCompNode) Line 7462   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CUIElement::GetRedirectionTransformsAndParentCompNode(CRenderTarget * pRenderTarget, TransformAndClipStack * pTransformsToParentCompNode, CMILMatrix * pTransformToRoot, unsigned int * pIsTransformToRootAnimating, unsigned int * pAreAllAncestorsVisible, HWCompTreeNode * * ppNearestCompNode) Line 7495    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderProperties(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileInheritedCollapsed, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransparent, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileLayoutClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransformTooSmall) Line 441   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::Render(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int redirectedDraw) Line 199 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderContentAndChildren(CUIElement * pUIElement, HWRenderParams & myRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int elementHasCompNode) Line 3461    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderProperties(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileInheritedCollapsed, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransparent, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileLayoutClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransformTooSmall) Line 629   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::Render(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int redirectedDraw) Line 199 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderContentAndChildren(CUIElement * pUIElement, HWRenderParams & myRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int elementHasCompNode)  C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderProperties(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileInheritedCollapsed, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransparent, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileLayoutClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransformTooSmall) Line 629   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::Render(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int redirectedDraw) Line 199 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderContentAndChildren(CUIElement * pUIElement, HWRenderParams & myRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int elementHasCompNode) Line 3461    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderProperties(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int requiresRedirectedDrawing, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileInheritedCollapsed, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransparent, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileLayoutClippedOut, unsigned int * pSkipRenderWhileTransformTooSmall) Line 629   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::Render(CUIElement * pUIElement, const HWRenderParams & parentRP, D2DRenderContext & d2dRenderContext, unsigned int redirectedDraw) Line 199 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!HWWalk::RenderRoot(CUIElement * pVisualRoot, CRenderTarget * pRenderTarget, HWInstance * pPersistentRenderDataSentinel, HWCrossFrameResources * pCrossFrameResources, HWFrameData * pPreviousFrameData, unsigned int backgroundColor, unsigned int forceRedraw, unsigned int needsToReleaseHardwareResources, unsigned int isOverdrawHeatMapEnabled, TransformAndClipStack * pPrependTransformAndClip, const CMILMatrix & displayOrientationTransform, const CMILMatrix & displayOrientationTransformInverse, unsigned int forceAllSlotsDirty, HWCompTreeNode * * ppRootNode, BrushCloneList * * ppBrushCloneList, unsigned int * pHasRenderedContent) Line 3847    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CCoreServices::RenderWalk(HWWalk * pHWWalk, ICoreRenderTarget * pIRenderTarget, VisualTree * pVisualTree, CSwapChainBackgroundPanel * pSCBP, unsigned int uBackgroundColor, unsigned int forceRedraw, unsigned int needsToReleaseHardwareResources, unsigned int isOverdrawHeatMapEnabled, unsigned int forceAllSlotsDirty) Line 11478  C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CCoreServices::NWDrawTree(HWWalk * pHWWalk, ICoreRenderTarget * pIRenderTarget, VisualTree * pVisualTree, unsigned int uBackgroundColor, unsigned int forceRedraw, unsigned int needsToReleaseHardwareResources, XRECT_WH * prcDirtyRect) Line 10985    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CCoreServices::NWDrawMainTree(ICoreRenderTarget * pIRenderTarget, unsigned int fForceRedraw, unsigned int needsToReleaseHardwareResources, XRECT_WH * prcDirtyRect) Line 10697  C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw(ICoreServices * pCore, unsigned int fForceRedraw, XRECT_WH * prcDirtyRect) Line 128   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick() Line 1160 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CXcpDispatcher::Tick() Line 1120    C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CJupiterControl::HandleWindowMessage(unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 249  C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CJupiterWindow::WindowProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 354 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CJupiterWindow::StaticWindowProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 208   C++
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@36()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@24()  Unknown
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage(int bDrainQueue, int * pbAnyMessages) Line 110    C++
Windows.UI.dll!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents(Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption options) Line 184   C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop() Line 416 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CJupiterControl::RunMessageLoop() Line 714  C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop() Line 2538 C++
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Run() Line 91  C++
twinapi.dll!`Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::RuntimeClassInitialize'::`55'::<lambda_A2234BA2CCD64E2C>::operator()(void * pv) Line 560   C++
twinapi.dll!`Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::RuntimeClassInitialize'::`55'::<lambda_A2234BA2CCD64E2C>::<helper_func>(void * pv) Line 613    C++
SHCore.dll!_SHWaitForThreadWithWakeMask@12()    Unknown
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

The only thing I can think of is that somewhere I should be manually marshalling a call to the UI thread with `CoreDispather.Invoke`, but I'm at a loss for where.

If any MSFT-y has the source and wants to look at the file that's causing the issue, the debugger is pointing me towards `d:\win8_gdr\windows\dxaml\xcp\core\core\elements\uielement.cpp`, which is obviously not on my system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer, taken from the SettingsFlyout example (but not the Popup example).

The SettingsFlyout example has you add

```
parentPopup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
```

to the Popup, with the methods being

```
private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.WindowActivationState == Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
        {
            parentPopup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

void OnPopupClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        Window.Current.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
    }
```

This seems to have fixed the crashes. I haven't been able to get it to repro no matter how vigorously I attack the Show Flyout button.